# Ubuntu 12.10 stopped during booting

Tags: boot

Good morning,
I'm very new to Ubuntu. I decided to change to Ububtu (12.10) for my old laptop (`Compaq Presario R3000` with `AMD Athlon XP 2800+`) that previously used `Windows XP`. After the installation, the PC restarted but, after a certain activity of the HDD stopped. Menwhile, no information from the screen (blank). Then I retried in recovery mode and the activity stopped at a certain point. I write the last two lines:

```
[    11.020922] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: >cs: IO port probe 0x3000-0x7fff:
[    11.021676]  excluding 0x3000-0x30ff 0x3400-0x34ff 0x3800-0x38ff 0x3c00-0x3cff
```

I don't know how to solve the problem. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you add more hardware specs, specifically, RAM and the graphics.

Comment: Did you to an upgrade or a fresh install? Are you able to at least boot to the Grub menu?

Comment: AMD Athlon XP 2800+, 2GB RAM, Nvidia GeForce 4. Fresh install.

Comment: Re-installed Ubuntu (full replacement option). Failed first reboot. Then successfully rebooted (don't know how) and asked me for install the available upgrades (I lei it upgrade everything). Then rebooted but it displayed an empty desktop. After exiting and restarting, it failed reboot again!

Comment: No idea? I found a previous post (see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/204905/compaq-presario-r3000-randomly-fails-to-boot-on-11-10-12-04-12-10) left without answer. I tried other distribution with the same failure: I will re-install Ubuntu (maybe a version previous to 11.10, if available) but I think it is a kernel problem with the pcmcia device. But I'm not so deep with Linux to know how to ignore its controller and skip the problem (considering that Linux stops during boot).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer from here: [Compaq Presario R3000 randomly fails to boot on 11.10, 12.04, 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204905/compaq-presario-r3000-randomly-fails-to-boot-on-11-10-12-04-12-10/381607#381607)

I had exactly the same problem. The laptop would freeze on boot up most but not every time.

I found this page: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42715

The bug still seems to exist but there is a workaround by adding the boot option in Grub:

```
pcmcia_rsrc.probe_io=0
```

It turns off pcmcia io probing in the pcmcia_rsrc kernel module. It fixed the problem for me.